# Fetch the created time of a like on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a method to fetch the created time of a like on a facebook's post using the graph search or fql?

Comment: See : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

Comment: No. You can't fetch the created time for a Like using Graph API or FQL.

Comment: And how can i do it? Is there a way without Graph API or FQL?

Comment: If the API does not support it, it is impossible. Facebook decided to not expose this information to the API ( I guess to respect privacy )

Comment: @Roy M J : There is no **created_time** field of table **like**. So, how you can do it ?